# How to add custom formatting to Redactor

Tags: redactor

I'm wondering if it's possible to add custom formatting to redactor? I created a custom button, and I'm able to change the formatting of text, but only using certain elements:

['p', 'blockquote', 'pre', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5']

However, I'm not able to add any of the following:

['small', 'figcaption']

I followed the Redactor docs to set up the button, and here is my function that is being called:

```
  var selected_html = $('#redactor_content').getSelected();
  $('#redactor_content').execCommand('formatblock', '<small>');
```

I also tried adding elements to my 'formattingTags' array, but it didn't seem to have any affect.

formattingTags: ['p', 'blockquote', 'small', 'pre', 'h3', 'h4']

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.

I added the following to my button function:

```
var $selected_html = $('#redactor_content').getSelected();
$('#redactor_content').execCommand('inserthtml', '<small>' + $selected_html + '</small>');
```

However, this is not perfect as  it does not replace the parent tag, and you can keep adding elements within elements.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
redactorOptionsDefaults = {
    buttonsAdd: {},
    activeButtonsAdd: {},
    buttonsCustom: {}
};

redactorOptionsDefaults.buttonsCustom.small = {
    title: 'small Header',
    callback: function () {
        this.formatBlocks('small');
    }
}
redactorOptionsDefaults.activeButtonsAdd.small = 'small';
```

It formatting block, highlight button if needed while selecting block. But don't remove style while repeat button click